# JavaFX path : non wanted lines

Tags: javafx, drawing

I'm trying to draw a race track, with turns, using JavaFX.

I delimit the lanes by drawing the shapes with a path on my GraphicsContext.

The problem is I never got to make arcTo work, so I'm using arc which from what I understood always draw counter clockwise, and that makes drawing my turns hard, here's the best result I got :

[image: malformed track]

`innerRadius` is the distance between the center and (x1, y1), and `radius` is the distance between the center and (x0, y0).

Here's my code:

```
    gc.beginPath();

    gc.moveTo(x1, y1);
    gc.lineTo(x0, y0);

    gc.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, radius, startAngle, arcLength);

    gc.lineTo(x3, y3);

    gc.arc(centerX, centerY, innerRadius, innerRadius, startAngle, arcLength);

    gc.closePath();
```

I don't know how to make the path not include the line from (x2, y2) to (x1, y1).
I'd rather stick to arc, but if you know how to make arcTo work with the variables I have, go ahead.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in this line:

```
gc.arc(centerX, centerY, innerRadius, innerRadius, startAngle, arcLength);
```

Here the starting angle is "down" and the arc should be drawn counter-clockwise just the way the outer arc was drawn. You want to draw the arc in the opposite direction though requiring you to use different parameters for the arc:

```
gc.arc(centerX, centerY, innerRadius, innerRadius, startAngle + arcLength, -arcLength);
```

You can also get rid of one of the `lineTo`s, since `closePath` automatically makes to connection to the start of the path.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(400, 400);
    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    gc.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    gc.setFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY);

    final double centerX = 100;
    final double centerY = 200;

    final double dR = 20;
    final double radius = (350 - centerY) / 2;
    final double innerRadius = radius - dR;

    final double x0 = centerX;
    final double y0 = centerY + radius;

    final double x3 = x0 + innerRadius;
    final double y3 = centerY;

    final double startAngle = 270;
    final double arcLength = 90;

    gc.beginPath();

    gc.moveTo(x0, y0);
    gc.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, radius, startAngle, arcLength);
    gc.lineTo(x3, y3);
    gc.arc(centerX, centerY, innerRadius, innerRadius, startAngle + arcLength, -arcLength);

    gc.closePath();

    gc.fill();
    gc.stroke();

    Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(canvas));

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. I'm mad at me for not thinking about it, but the documentation didn't mention we could use negative lengths, even though that makes perfect sense.
Have a nice day.